# Assign a value to a property depending on initialized Class

Tags: vb.net

I try to assign a value (`Test1`) to a Property (`Wealth`) dynamically so that depending on the initialized Class the calculated value is different. But all I get as a result is 0. Could anyone explain me why and how I can solve the problem.

```
Public Class Class1
    Private _test1 As Integer

    Overridable ReadOnly Property Test1 As Integer
        Get
            Return _test1
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Wealth As Integer
        Get
            Dim rnd As New Random
            Dim val As Integer = rnd.Next(1, 6)
            Return val * _test1
        End Get
    End Property

End Class

Public Class Class2
    Inherits Class1

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Test1 As Integer
        Get
            Return 3
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Initialisation:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim t As New Class2
        MsgBox(t.Wealth.ToString)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the private variable, you need to reference the property itself.

```
Public Class Form1
  Public Class Class1

    Overridable ReadOnly Property Test1 As Integer
      Get
        Return 0 'Default value'
      End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Wealth As Integer
      Get
        Dim rnd As New Random
        Dim val As Integer = rnd.Next(1, 6)
        Return val * Test1 'Changed! Uses the Property name, so that if it is overridden it uses the new version'
      End Get
    End Property

  End Class

  Public Class Class2
    Inherits Class1

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Test1 As Integer
      Get
        Return 3
      End Get
    End Property

  End Class

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim t As New Class2
    MsgBox(t.Wealth.ToString)
  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Great, exactely what i was looking for and i even understand why it is not working in my case. Cheers!

Comment: Hi! The first part is working but now at home I see that "Return val * Test1" has still the private variable. so this is not working.

Comment: Which local value? "val"? It's a locally defined random number in your original code. What are you actually trying to do with this code? Is it for a game? Because at the moment, the "Wealth" function will return a different value each time you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a constructor.

```
Public Class Class1
 Public Sub New(int As Integer)
  Me.test1 = int
 End sub
 ...
```

Then when you declare it

```
Dim t As New Class1(5)
MsgBox(t.Wealth.ToString)
```

Comment: I refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004381/overridable-constant 's confirmed answer and thought there is a workaround not to use a constructor or even constant solution.

Comment: Ok, follow your heart. Not sure how that is relevant to your problem.